# Стилизация option

Tags: javascript, css

Почему стили для списка `option` применяются только в Firefox, а как сделать для остальных браузеров?
Надо, чтобы фон при наведении был другим.

```css
option:hover {
  background: #0c6eb9 linear-gradient(#0c6eb9, #0c6eb9);
}

option {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
      <option>-</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Только если вы сделаете собственный `select` с помощью JS

Comment: то есть взять обычный список ul и извращаться над ним?

Comment: Ну я обычно для таких целей использовал div, но а там по желанию

Comment: Попробуйту
https://select2.github.io/